How to get access to a specific single spell, regardless of list?
I'm an Arcanist.
I want to be able to use Paragon Surge, but I'm not a half-elf, nor can I qualify for being one in any way.
I know there's Clerical version of Paragon Surge that works for any race (the Self-Realization Domain version to be precise).
I'm looking for a way to get access to that specific spell (and specific variant) somehow, not as a 1-time deal (scrolls or wands) but something that I could use every single day with no additional costs.
Only way I know of but I don't want to use, because it has way too big of a feat tax is Loremaster > Secret Class Feature > Secret of Magical Discipline Feat.
Only RAW answers please, excluding Wish shenanigans.

Access to that spell is easy, as it's on many spell-lists, and you can just buy scrolls and UMD it. The racial tag does not mean only Half-Elves can GET this spell. The difficulty with Paragon Surge is that the spell can only TARGET Half-Elves (except for the Self-Realization domain spell version).

I meant day-to-day usage. Scrolls or even Wands are way too expensive for daily usage. I specified this in an edit.

Faith Magic
The Wizard's Faith Magic arcane discovery gives you a spell specifically from a domain. This can be the special Paragon Surge spell from the Self-Realization subdomain. This requires the Wizard being able to cast a 6th-level spell, which corresponds to an 11th-level Wizard.

Magic Items
Since a Cleric can craft a scroll or staff with the Paragon Surge domain spell inside, it's also possible to use a scroll or staff with the Paragon Surge domain spell. A staff can be used up to 10 times (11 with an Arcane Battery) a day, though only recharged with a single charge per day.

False Channel
If a normal staff is insufficient, then a Razmiran/False Priest Sorcerer's Razmiran/False Channel ability allows the Sorcerer to expend a spell-slot of higher level to cast a spell from a scroll, wand, or staff without expending the magic item or its charge. Such a Sorcerer can cast that spell as often as desired, provided sufficient 5th-level or higher spell-slots.

Ring of Spell Knowledge
Any arcane spontaneous caster can use a Ring of Spell Knowledge IV to store the Paragon Surge domain spell after encountering it (and succeeding at a DC 20 Spellcraft check). This allows unlimited casting of the spell, provided sufficient 4th-level or higher spell-slots.

Answering my own question.
Option 1:

Possession on a half-elf, then using Paragon Surge and (depending on whether intended feat is physical or mental) either finishing whatever needs to be done in possessed body or ending Possession and doing the rest in own body.
Works even better with Leadership and followers, since they are both expendable and won't complain, unlike Possessing strangers, which could cause many story-related problems.

Option 2:

Secret of Magical Discipline feat unlocked by Loremaster Prestige Class feature Secrets.


Answering your own question is fine, but your question was about getting access to the specific Cleric domain spell Paragon Surge, not the normal Paragon Surge. You also spelled out two conditions in your question:
1) "I'm not a half-elf, nor can I qualify for being one in any way", and 2) "I don't want to use [...] Loremaster > Secret of Magical Discipline Feat."
Then you answer with 1) "Possession on a half-elf, then using Paragon Surge" [i.e. qualifying as a Half-Elf], and 2) "Secret of Magical Discipline feat unlocked by Loremaster." Are you serious?

Added it just for completion sake if someone else looks for same thing but with different criteria.
